# How to prevent simultaneous textfield focus?

Tags: flutter

I have a form which has 3 inputs inside it, I tried to move the focus by tapping directly to the next input, but then the input before it remains focused. I do not want this to be happened. For better explanation, please have a look at this GIF.

[image: visual explanation]

As you can see, the first input remains focused. How can I fix this?

Please have a look at my script, do I have any mistake?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
import 'package:prismahr/components/ensure_visible_when_focused.dart';

class ReimburseCreatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  ReimburseCreatePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ReimburseCreatePageState createState() => _ReimburseCreatePageState();
}

class _ReimburseCreatePageState extends State<ReimburseCreatePage> {
  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  List<Asset> _images = List<Asset>();

  Future<void> _getImages() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 8,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: _images,
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarTitle: 'Upload Receipts',
          allViewTitle: 'All Images',
          useDetailsView: false,
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint('$e');
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _images = resultList;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FocusNode _titleFocusNode = FocusNode();
    FocusNode _nominalFocusNode = FocusNode();
    FocusNode _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();

    String _title;
    String _nominal;
    String _description;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black87),
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Reimburse',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 16.0),
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: controller,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 20, 16, 100),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildDropzone(),
                EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
                  focusNode: _titleFocusNode,
                  child: FormInput(
                    focusNode: _titleFocusNode,
                    label: 'Short Description',
                    hintText: 'Eg. Travel Expenses',
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    onChanged: (title) {
                      setState(() {
                        _title = title;
                      });
                    },
                    onSubmitted: (val) {
                      _nominalFocusNode.requestFocus();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
                  focusNode: _nominalFocusNode,
                  child: FormInput(
                    focusNode: _nominalFocusNode,
                    label: 'Nominal',
                    hintText: 'Eg. 10000',
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    onChanged: (nominal) {
                      setState(() {
                        _nominal = nominal;
                      });
                    },
                    onSubmitted: (val) {
                      _descriptionFocusNode.requestFocus();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
                  focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                  child: FormInput(
                    focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                    label: 'Detailed Description',
                    hintText: 'Eg. I made this because...',
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    onChanged: (description) {
                      setState(() {
                        _description = description;
                      });
                    },
                    onSubmitted: (val) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 16),
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 90,
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: Text(
                  'Submit',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDropzone() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          offset: Offset(0.00, 10.00),
          color: Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(0.05),
          blurRadius: 20,
        ),
      ]),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, left: 5.0),
            child: Text(
              'Receipts',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: InkWell(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 16.0),
                child: _images != null && _images.length > 0
                    ? _buildPreviewGrid()
                    : _buildLabel(),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                _getImages();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPreviewGrid() {
    return GridView.count(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      children: List.generate(_images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = _images[index];
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: AssetThumb(
            asset: asset,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLabel() {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.cloud_upload,
              size: 50,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Upload Receipt',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(
            'Please upload one or more receipts',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12.0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final bool obsecureText;
  final String hintText;
  final String errorText;
  final int maxLines;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final TextInputAction textInputAction;
  final Function(String) onChanged;
  final Function(String) onSubmitted;

  const FormInput({
    Key key,
    @required this.label,
    @required this.focusNode,
    this.obsecureText,
    this.hintText,
    this.errorText,
    this.keyboardType,
    this.textInputAction,
    this.onChanged,
    this.onSubmitted,
    this.maxLines,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 5),
            child: Text(
              this.label,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0.00, 10.00),
                color: Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(0.05),
                blurRadius: 20,
              ),
            ]),
            child: TextField(
              focusNode: this.focusNode,
              keyboardType: this.keyboardType ?? TextInputType.text,
              textInputAction: this.textInputAction ?? TextInputAction.done,
              obscureText: this.obsecureText ?? false,
              maxLines: this.maxLines ?? 1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: this.hintText,
                errorText: this.errorText,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              onChanged: this.onChanged,
              onSubmitted: this.onSubmitted,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you have your `FocusNodes` initialized in your build method move them out of your build method and initialize them globally and you should be all set.

Comment: no problem such a weird problem such an easy fix :)

Comment: I had same problem. Turns out the dev who worked before me on current project had made a custom textformfield widget for use throughout the app. He had written `focusNode : FocusNode(),` inside its build method. I was left scratching my head for hours.